# Bluetooth discoverable functopm

Tags: android, bluetooth

Hi for the below code.

For example I only want my device to search for other bluetooth devices and not other devices search for mine. So I can omit the below code out?

```
Intent discoverableIntent = new
Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE);
discoverableIntent.putExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_DISCOVERABLE_DURATION, 300);
startActivity(discoverableIntent);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code would create a UI dialog asking the user to put the device in a discoverable state for 300 seconds. I you don't want the device to be discovered, you can omit it.